# Type mismatch with generics

Tags: java, generics, types, mismatch

Here's an interface:

```
public interface Foo<T> extends Comparable<Foo<T>>  {
   ...
}
```

And there are some classes implementing this interface:

```
public class Bar extends Something implements Foo<Something> {
    public Vector<Foo<Bar>> giveBar() {
        ...
    }
}

public class Boo extends SomethingElse implements Foo<SomethingElse> {
    public Vector<Foo<Boo>> giveBoo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to keep a bunch of Foos (that may really be Foos or Boos) inside a vector.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
Boo boo = new Boo();
Vector<Foo<?>> vector;
if (...) 
   vector = bar.giveBar();
else
   vector = boo.giveBoo();
```

I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Vector<Foo<SomethingElse>> to Vector<Foo<?>>
```

The same goes for:

```
Vector<Foo> vector;
if (...) 
   vector = giveBar();
else
   vector = giveBoo();
```

Is a superclass that both Bar and Boo extend the only solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What all that code boils down to is:

```
Vector<A> vector = new Vector<B>();
```

In this case B extends A, but that's not allowed because the types don't match. To make clear why this doesn't work, imagine the following code:

```
Vector<Vector<?>> vector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
vector.add(new Vector<Integer>());
```

The variable's type is of a *vector of vectors of unknown type*; and what's being assigned to it is a *vector of vectors of strings*. The second line adds a *vector of integers* to that. The component type of the variable `Vector<?>`, which accepts `Vector<Integer>`; but the actual vector's component type is `Vector<String>`, which doesn't. If the compiler didn't object to the assignment on the first line, it would allow you to write the incorrect second line without being spotted.

C#'s generics have a similar restriction, but the difference is that a generic class in C# stores it component type, while Java forgets component types when the code is compiled.

ps - Why on earth are you using `Vector` rather than `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`? Is it because there are threading issues involved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Vector<? extends Foo<?>> vector;
```